# Anchor link for TOC with duplicate name

Tags: .net, markdown

I am using Azure DevOps markdown to write an API document and I am having trouble creating anchor link in its table of content - TOC.

```
- [API One](#api-one)
  - [Request](#request)
- [API Two](#api-two)
  - [Request](#request-two)

<a name="api-one"></a>
## API One
<a name="request"></a>
### Request
<a name="api-two"></a>
## API Two
<a name="request-two"></a>
### Request
```

Only first 3 anchor links worked.  How can I get the last link to work without rename "Request" to another unique value and update its anchor link to reflect the name change?

I don't think ADO support HTML in its mark down

[image]